# populating listview in OnLoad Function

Tags: c#

I am developing an application in which I am using comboBox and ListView. I want to show the records in Listview from database when the application is launched. And the combBox is used for filtering to display those records in ListView, specified by the comboBox.The problem is that when i launch my application it does not show any thing in ListView (both comboBox and ListView are populated from database). while the comboBox is populated and ListView is not populated. And when I select an item in comboBox, it shows those data in listView. I have used a separate class for dataBase connectivity. my Code is below.

```
private void EmployeeAttendence_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                table = dbOperation.select("employs.emp_id, employs.emp_name, employs.emp_fname, designation.name from employs inner join designation on designation.id = employs.designation");
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[1].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[2].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[3].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add("P");
                }

                table = dbOperation.select("* from designation");
                comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                comboBox1.DataSource = table;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is the comboBox filtering coding.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                table = dbOperation.select("employs.emp_id, employs.emp_name, employs.emp_fname, designation.name from employs inner join designation on designation.id = employs.designation where employs.designation = '" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'");

                listView1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[1].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[2].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[3].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add("P");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

And this is my Database Select Query Coding.

```
public DataTable select(string table_name)
        {
            table = new DataTable();
            command.CommandText = "select " + table_name;
            command.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            con.Close();
            return table;
        }
```

Comment: What platform are you coding for? Asp? WinForms? etc...

Comment: (both comboBox and ListView are populated from database). while the comboBox is populated and ListView is not populated.

Comment: i want the listview to be populated with the whole data retrieved from the database when the form is loaded. After loading the form now when i select an item in the comboBox then the listView is to be populated according to the selected item of the comboBox.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're working with windows form...

And I think the problem is that you want the listbox to be populated with the first item of the combobox when you load for the first time the winform

So, in the form_load event you should select the index in the combobox

```
private void EmployeeAttendence_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        table = dbOperation.select("employs.emp_id, employs.emp_name, employs.emp_fname, designation.name from employs inner join designation on designation.id = employs.designation");
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[1].ToString());
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[2].ToString());
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[3].ToString());
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add("P");
        }

        table = dbOperation.select("* from designation");
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox1.DataSource = table;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";

        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //this should raise the event comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) and the listbox will be populated

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try To add `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` in Page_Load Event

```
    private void EmployeeAttendence_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          try
          {
              table = dbOperation.select("employs.emp_id, employs.emp_name, employs.emp_fname, designation.name from employs inner join designation on designation.id = employs.designation");
              listView1.Items.Clear();
              foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
              {
                listView1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[1].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[2].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[3].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add("P");
              }

              table = dbOperation.select("* from designation");
              comboBox1.Items.Clear();
              comboBox1.DataSource = table;
              comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
              comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: He/She may be coding for WinForms, which makes this answer irrelevant.

Comment: Yes you are right. But if He/She Using ASP.NET then it's due to Page PostBack and if Windows Forms Used then after Page_Load Event combo_selectedIndexChanged Event is fired. so i think he/she isn't selecting combo-box default value that's why it's happening.